# SQLSyntaxErrorException: "[" at line 7, column 52

Tags: java, mysql, database, syntax-error

Getting this syntax error for line 7 but I have no code there. Here's what my code looks like so far. The blank space after recruitment.package is line 7.

```
package recruitment.project;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
```

```
try {
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    String query2 = "INSERT INTO APP.Shortlist(ClientID, WorkerID)\n" +
                        "SELECT ClientID, WorkerID\n" +
                        "FROM APP.CLIENT_TABLE, APP.WORKER_TABLE\n" +
                        "WHERE APP.CLIENT_TABLE.WORKER_NEEDED = APP.WORKER_TABLE.JOB_1 OR\n" + 
                        "APP.CLIENT_TABLE.WORKER_NEEDED = APP.WORKER_TABLE.JOB_2 OR\n" +
                        "APP.CLIENT_TABLE.WORKER_NEEDED = APP.WORKER_TABLE.JOB_3 AND\n" +
                        "APP.CLIENT_TABLE.CLIENTID =  " +
                        "" +jTextField1;

    PreparedStatement prepStat = con.prepareStatement(query2);



    prepStat.executeUpdate();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)Shortlist_Table.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
    Show_ShortlistInput_In_JTable();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record saved.");

} catch (HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, still very new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually coming from the SQL interpreter and it is arising because you're not using prepared statements properly. You should be preparing a statement with a placeholder and then assigning a value to that placeholder. For your case:

```
String query2 = "INSERT INTO APP.Shortlist(ClientID, WorkerID)\n" +
                    "SELECT ClientID, WorkerID\n" +
                    "FROM APP.CLIENT_TABLE, APP.WORKER_TABLE\n" +
                    "WHERE APP.CLIENT_TABLE.WORKER_NEEDED = APP.WORKER_TABLE.JOB_1 OR\n" + 
                    "APP.CLIENT_TABLE.WORKER_NEEDED = APP.WORKER_TABLE.JOB_2 OR\n" +
                    "APP.CLIENT_TABLE.WORKER_NEEDED = APP.WORKER_TABLE.JOB_3 AND\n" +
                    "APP.CLIENT_TABLE.CLIENTID =  ?";

PreparedStatement prepStat = con.prepareStatement(query2);
prepStat.setString(1, jTextField1);
prepStat.executeUpdate();
```

Note that you probably have an error in your logic, I suspect it should be

```
                    "WHERE (APP.CLIENT_TABLE.WORKER_NEEDED = APP.WORKER_TABLE.JOB_1 OR\n" + 
                    "APP.CLIENT_TABLE.WORKER_NEEDED = APP.WORKER_TABLE.JOB_2 OR\n" +
                    "APP.CLIENT_TABLE.WORKER_NEEDED = APP.WORKER_TABLE.JOB_3) AND\n" +
                    "APP.CLIENT_TABLE.CLIENTID =  ?";
```

Note the `()` around the `OR` parts.

Comment: Hey thanks for helping, I think that worked but now getting a new error. That I cannot compare Worker_Needed against Job_1, Job_2 etc. I think this is because Job_1, 2, 3 are values from case statement. How would I change them to string to compare?

Comment: @LucaCassin Without seeing the case statement it's hard to say. I would suggest posting a new question about the new error and include that information as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help I fixed my error and now code is working. Appreciate it.